# How to expand a textarea in selenium webdriver when the element path is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

The textarea I need to expand has a dynamic xpath and I possibly can't use:

```
(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('someID').setAttribute('rows', '50')");
(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('someID').setAttribute('cols', '60')");
```

because the attributes ID, value, class etc are all dynamic.
Is there any other way to resize the textarea?
The HTML code for element is

```
<textarea name="comments" id="isc_4G3" $89="isc_TextAreaItem_25" $9a="$9b" class="textItem" style="margin:0px;WIDTH:1132px;HEIGHT:60px;" autocomplete="OFF" spellcheck="true" wrap="SOFT" tabindex="1863" oninput="isc_TextAreaItem_25.$43g()" handlenativeevents="false"></textarea>
```

Also, I had tried

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(getInternalNotesTextArea()).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(xOffset, yOffset).release().perform();
```

which did not work on it.

Comment: Can you provide more info as: 1. What have you tried? Show code. 2. What worked for you? 3. Where are you stuck? 4. Provide relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: Please post some html code of the required element?

Comment: I added the HTML code for this element in the question.

Comment: The height and width are set via inline styles. Try changing those.

Comment: Thanks Mark Lapierre. It worked when I tried setting height and width via inline styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the piece of code that worked for me

```
WebElement textArea= getNotesTextArea();
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'WIDTH:1132px;HEIGHT:365px');", textArea);
```

where, `getNotesTextArea()` returned the `textarea` with dynamic `xpath`.

Comment: In my answer I tried to explain how to pass element as argument in selenium javascript executer. So that you can make generic method.And yes to increase the height and width of text area you need to change style attribute. But In automation testing it is not advisable to change element attribute like this.

Comment: Shailendra , Indeed your answer helped me to know how to pass element as argument in selenium javascript executor but that piece of code did not expand the textarea. So, I had to use this.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic attribute find element using XPATH. And Pass webelement is executescript.

```
WebElement textArea= webDriver.findElement(xpath_of_textarea);

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;

executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('rows', '50');", textArea);
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('cols', '60');", textArea);
```

I hope it will help

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. It doesn't throw any exception either, just won't expand the textarea.